# How to access conda installed on windows using WSL2

Tags: python, anaconda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am working on windows 10 & I've installed Anaconda on it. Recently I created a conda environment in windows & downloaded python, jupyter & some dependencies inside it.

Now I've installed wsl2 & wanted to access the already created conda environment on windows.
I've tried activating the env from wsl2 but it doesn't seem to work.

I am looking to access the conda envs from wsl2 so I can run scripts & if that's not possible then I would like to find a method of installing anaconda from wsl2 without overriding or interfering with the existing anaconda installed on my windows system.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you can call the .sh executable of conda from its path and activate the environment. I have done such thing on remote computers on bash and that worked.

Have a look into this: https://gist.github.com/kauffmanes/5e74916617f9993bc3479f401dfec7da

you might find some information about running conda on wsl2. Let me know if that works